# Open Vimdiff with multiple windows in different read/write permissions?

Tags: vim

I am opening 3 windows using vimdiff with file1, file2, file3, etc. I would like to have file3 be in edit mode, and file1 and file2 to be in read only mode.

Is this possible?

This is my command...

```
vimdiff -R file1 file2 -c :topleft sp file3
```

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me:

```
vimdiff -R file1 file2 -c ':se noreadonly' file3
```